# What is the best practice of type conversion overloading?

Tags: c++, casting

```
class A
{
public:
    A ( unsigned _a ) : a (_a)
    {
    }
    operator unsigned& () 
    {
        return a;
    }
    operator const unsigned () const
    {
        return a;
    }
    unsigned a; 
};
```

In the above example, I created two type conversion operators, one gives reference, one gives a copy. Both have drawbacks. Any suggestion?

---

Since type conversion operator is allowed in C++, how can we make best use of it and where?

Comment: If you make `operator unsigned ()` const (i.e., `operator unsigned () const`), then you can (and should) have both.

Comment: please also make sure you read enough of the online material telling why its a bad idea to have conversion operator (they not called "cast operator" since its a conversion, not a cast. and no, there is no such thing as an "implcit cast")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about making the second one `const` as you're returning a copy anyway.  That will remove the ambiguity:

```
class A
{
public:
    A ( unsigned _a ) : a (_a)
    {
    }
    operator unsigned& () 
    {
        return a;
    }
    operator unsigned () const // make this one const
    {
        return a;
    }
    unsigned a; 
};
```

Comment: The best practice is probably not to overload these operators, unless there is a pressing need. This is definitely not something you do "because it would be convenient for the caller".